# How to get a count of each record in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables, `users` and `orders` to track orders placed by each user.

I want to get a list of each user, and the total number of orders.

For an individual, I could use:

```
SELECT users.name, (select count(*) from orders where orders.users_id = 1) as total
from users
where users.id = 1
```

Is there an efficient way to do this for *all* users simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT users.name, (select count(*) from orders where orders.users_id = users.id) as total
from users
```

But a better way is with a join.

```
SELECT users.name, IFNULL(COUNT(orders.id), 0) AS total
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.users_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

It may actually be better to join with a subquery that aggregates, rather than aggregating after joining:

```
SELECT u.name, IFNULL(o.total, 0) AS total
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT users_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY users_id) AS o ON u.id = o.users_id
```

Comment: Better because?

Comment: I think MySQL optimizes it better.

Answer (score 1):

The key is really a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(*)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.users_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Comment: You should make it clear that using `INNER JOIN` will leave out users who have no orders.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like that too, in this case only will return when there are records on order :

```
   SELECT users.name, count(*) 
     from users
     join orders On orders.users_id = users.id  

    group by users.name
```

Comment: He doesn't want `where users.id = 1`, he wants it for all users.

Comment: `count(*)` will give the wrong answer for users with no orders. It will say `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Sorry, I want use a JOIN unless LEFT JOIN then will return only when have records in orders table, but your solution with IFNULL is better!

Comment: You still need to remove `where users.id = 1`.

Comment: I assume that is a parameter to be send by the user, because he passed it in his question

Comment: The question shows the code for just one user at a time. He said he wants to get the counts for *all* users.

Comment: Edited! Thanks 